# screen out document results that share the same property value accept the first one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a db of documents. Every document has a property(keyword) called index (noting to do with the elastic index) and a property(keyword) named superIndex. There can be multiple documents with the same index and multiple documents with the same superIndex in the DB, these fields are not unique.

I run a compound query searching free text on the text content of these documents, with sorting, and get the results I want. However, I get many documents having the same index and/or superIndex. Currently I programmatically filter the result list and take only the first result from each index and superIndex. My requirement is that at the end I'm left with the top results from the sort, the first from each index and superIndex.

Can this be done using elastic query. If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Field collapsing allows you to collapse all search results having the same value in a field (e.g. `index`). (See Elasticsearch Reference: [Field Collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse))